# Entity Framework : timeout expired exceptions occurring during peak API activity

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

In an Open Shift cluster environment, I am having processing time periods where we are getting various timeout expired exceptions from Entity Framework Core v2.1. I am in the process of upgrading my app to .NET Core 6.0. The exceptions occur on queries to SQL Server and appear to not be related to memory or processing resources. Seems more likely that it is load on the network where we may be having network connection timeouts to the SQL Server.

Some of the exceptions also include the following case:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258

Looking at next steps, I have read some about Entity Framework interceptors. Would using Entity Framework interceptors be a good use of this feature for debugging timeout expired issues?

Could I use an interceptor to catch the timeout exception details, better inside the Entity Framework DLL?

Looking for best practices for pin pointing causes of DB connection timeouts occurring under peak loads, where simple DB queries are timing out.

Comment: We weren't able to upgrade to dotnet 6 with EF Core 2.2, because of exactly same errors, our solution were to upgrade to latest EF Core too - which worked.

Comment: And for determining issue type (connection vs query timeout) and identifiying next steps, there's an article which might be helpful - [Timeout expired messages when connecting to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/timeout-expired-error#determine-the-type-of-timeout-expired-errors). Besides exception logging, from code perspective I believe you can hardly do anything to analyze the root cause without connecting to directly SQL Server (like checking ongoing/executed jobs which might be the reason for timeouts).

Comment: We did contact the SQL DBA and they are not seeing any timeout in the Sql Server Logs.  I am not sure where I should focus my attention.  This problem occurs in both an API and Service application.